# A cat/human world where fur color determines rank

Tags: story-identification

There is a written story that I read a long time ago where it was about a race of cat/humans (humans with cat ears and tails) and the hierarchy is based on fur color.  Lighter the fur, higher rank you are.  One character (a female) was teleported from a sort of different dimension, where everyone was just human.  She was friends with royalty but wasn't royalty herself, though she can through with pure white tail and ears, which causes a lot of misunderstandings.  There's another character that has black and white ears and tail (and is royalty) because one of his parents was of lower rank.  It goes between 2 or 3 different characters and it has it's own webpage that I'm pretty sure is shared with a couple other webcomics/written stories that the same person created.

Comment: Hmm, a story about cats, asked by a user named "Pooch"...

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with this series so may be way off - but I hear sci/fi + cat aliens and think Larry Niven's Kzinti works - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kzin

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Survivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivor_(Octavia_Butler_novel)) by Octavia Butler? Notably the aliens establish rank (and something of a caste system) via fur colour.

> Survivor follows the early contact between the Missionaries, a group
>   of human colonists fleeing a plague on Earth, and the Kohn,
>   intelligent natives of the planet on which the Missionaries have
>   arrived. In particular, the novel focuses on Alanna, the adopted
>   daughter of the Missionaries' leader, as she attempts to prevent the
>   Missionaries' destruction or assimilation at the hands of a dominant
>   local culture. During the course of the novel, Alanna's experiences
>   assimilating and negotiating with the Kohn draw upon her earlier,
>   similar experience joining the Missionaries themselves, and Alanna's
>   ability to interact with the various cultures becomes the key to their
>   survival.

[image]